# Laravel Excel Maatwebsite 3.1 Row Validation Not Working

Tags: laravel-5.7, laravel-excel

I'm trying to find duplicated rows on the import array using the WithValidation concern (will use SkipsOnError to remove duplicated rows later). But the validation set in my import class to find the duplicated rows doesn't seems to work. 
No error is returned and all rows are imported to database when I upload an excel file (just a column with no headers)  containing duplicated data

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Contactlist;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithValidation;

class ContactsImport implements ToModel, WithValidation
{
    use Importable;

    private $data; 

    public function __construct(array $data = [])
    {
        $this->data = $data; 
    }

    public function model(array $row)
    {
        if (!isset($row[0])) {
            return null;
        }

        return new Contactlist(array_merge([
            'nums'   => $row[0],
        ], $this->data));

    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            //find duplicate records
            '0.*' => 'distinct',
            //'*.0' => 'distinct' Tried this also
        ];
  }

}
```

code snippet of my controller

```
$data = [
            'contact_id' => $contact->id,
        ];

        Excel::import(new ContactsImport($data), request()->file('contact_file'));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class ExempleImport implements ToCollection, WithHeadingRow
{

   /** @var Collection */
   public $collection;  


  /**
   * @param Collection $collection
   */
  public function collection(Collection $collection)
  {
    $this->collection = $collection->transform(function ($row) {

        $this->validationFields($row);

        return [
            'curso'             => $row['curso'],
            'marca'             => $row['marca'],
            'status'            => $row['status_do_curso'],
            'emissor'           => $row['emissor_cliente'],
            'nome_da_conta'     => $row['nome_da_conta'],
        ];
    });
  }

  public function validationFields( $row )
  {

      $customMessages = [
          'required' => 'O campo :attribute deve estar preenchido'
      ];

      Validator::make($row->toArray(), [
          'curso' => 'required',
          'marca' => 'required',
          'status_do_curso' => 'required',
          'emissor_cliente' => 'required',
          'nome_da_conta' => 'required',
      ], $customMessages)->validate();
 }
}
```

---

In your controller

```
    $exampleImport = new ExampleImport;

   try{
        Excel::import( $exampleImport, $updateFile);
    }catch ( ValidationException $e ){

        return response()->json(['success'=>'errorList','message'=> $e->errors()]);
    }
```

[image: Exemple image]

Comment: how can i test this? i have been trying to test it with correct and corrupted data but i can't tell whether it's working or not

Comment: Example code in controller: https://pastebin.com/qwTAC9Mq
code import: https://pastebin.com/N8trKQLd

Just create a csv or xls file containing the headers you want. Upload this file and, when you click upload, you must upload to a controller action you want, in my case the action is called: updateSpreadsheet

Comment: This is a saver solution, just add the line : if (!$row->filter()->isNotEmpty()) return null;
         before the validation call

Answer (score 0):

Got this working importing to collections

```
namespace App\Imports;

use App\Contactlist;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;

class ContactsImport implements ToCollection
{ 
private $data; 

public function __construct(array $data = [])
{
    $this->data = $data; 
}

/**
* @param array $row
*/
public function collection(Collection $rows)
{
    // Initialize number
    $numbers = array();

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        //Skip empty rows
        if (!isset($row[0])) 
        continue;

        //Skip number previously added using in_array
        if (in_array($row[0], $numbers))
            continue;

        Contactlist::create(array_merge([
            'nums'   => $row[0],
        ], $this->data));

        // Add new number to array
        $numbers[] = $row[0];
    }

 }

}
```

Comment: As you can see Edmund, I got a way around removing duplicate entries with the foreach and if statement in my answer code, as the 'WithValidation' I planned using in my first code didn't work